# Поиск с использованием regexp

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регексп `ж[аоые]лезн[оыа][ая] дв[ие]рь`. Надо, чтобы между `[оыа]` и `[ая]` была проверка `и`, `й`, или отсутствие данной буквы.

Как это реализовать каким-нибудь простым способом?

Comment: `"ж[аоые]лезн[оыа][йи]?[ая] дв[ие]рь"`

Comment: Скорее так: `ж[аоые]лезн[оыа][ийая] дв[ие]рь` или так: `ж[аоые]лезн[оыа]([йи]|[ая]) дв[ие]рь`

Comment: Добавь примеры. Непонятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать символьный класс `[йи]` и кванитификатор `?` для нахождения одной или нуля таких символов:

```
/ж[аоые]лезн[оыа][йи]?[ая] дв[ие]рь/
                 ^^^^^
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/uY1mJ7/1)